# Does Gmail enterprise allow an attachment larger than 25MB?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, gmail-attachments

Just what the title says, the regular Gmail (unpaid) has a limit of 25MB on a file attachment.

Does the same limit apply to Gmail Enterprise accounts too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, business and education accounts as well, have the same attachment limit of 25MB.
See here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=175121